# How to prevent Raspberry pi 3 from auto starting in an operating system after reboot?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, osmc, shutdown, reset

Sometimes, I don't like the Raspberry Pi to reboot into the last operating system used automatically , after 10 seconds. I want to be able to either prevent this entirely and/or choose a custom start timeout. Is there a software to put on the pi for this? Or is this even possible? I have been trying to research for about a week now, with no luck. Any help? I am using the newest version of Debian Stretch, the Raspbian OS, and the newest version of OSMC (Open Source Media Center), as the three operating systems that I use.

## Update:

**Here is what I mean:**
[image: Example]

Comment: How do you select the operating system now? Using GRUB? It would be a configuration option on whatever you use to select.

Comment: i use noobs? no sure what grubs is

Comment: @MarkSmith see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `bootmenutimeout=` to a higher value.
This setting is found in the `/boot/config.txt` file.